# MongoDB $text - return count of terms found?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, text-search

I have figured out using the $text in MongoDB to do text search in all the documents belonging to a collection, and get results back, and go through them. However I was trying to find out if there is way to get the frequency or the count of terms found per document?
Here is the code that I am using that allows me to go through the documents that matched the search term:

```
Model.find( 
     { $text : { $search : "FindThisString"}},
     { score : {$meta : "textScore"}}
  )
 .sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore'}})
 .exec(function(err, results) {
     _.each(results, function(item) {
        //console.log(item);
        console.log(item._id);
        console.log(item.score);
     });
});
```

For example in the code above - the "results" returned by Mongo/Mongoose would have the documents that match the search term. How can I get the number of terms it was found in that document?

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, couldn't you just do `results.length`

Comment: No - that will give the number of documents where the search term was found...